# Python. Shouldn't this work? Error says "NameError: name 'off' is not defined"

Tags: python, nameerror

Why does this give me an error when calc == off? The program should end after i is changed.

def calc():

```
i="i"

while i=="i":
    calc = input("Enter your calculation ")

    if calc!="off" or "Off":
        ans = eval(calc)
        print(ans)

    else:
        i="a"
```

Comment: You're supposed to use `raw_input()` in Python 2.

Comment: Your conditional statement is also somewhat... off.

Comment: or may be eval call is the culprit if you're using Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're `eval`ing the string in `calc`.  That's looking for a local variable named "off" which doesn't exist.

While we're on the subject of bad syntax, this doesn't work:

```
if calc!="off" or "Off":
```

You want this instead:

```
if calc not in ("off", "Off"):
```

or ideally:

```
if calc.lower() != "off":
```

Comment: That totally did it thanks. So out of curiosity what is "or" for?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting and criticizing me but pointing out the same mistake in your own answer.

Comment: @vulpix - pointing out the logic error was a secondary concern.  Your answer did not answer the question, which was "what is producing my NameError?".  If your answer does not _answer the question_ it deserves downvotes.